# Decompose a parametric curve into monotone segments

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a numerical computational method to decompose a parametric curve $C(t)$ by subdivision into xy-monotone segments. I searched the web thoroughly, but didn't find any usable relevant matter. I'm also interested in corresponding analytic methods.

Do you know such methods?

Comment: How the curve is given to you matters. Is it an analytical form, or is it a tabular form?

Comment: How is your curve given (as a graph $y=f(x)$? as a parametrised curve $(x(t),y(t)$?) and what do you mean by "monotone"?

Comment: The curve is parametric. I updated the question with this relevant information.

Comment: I've done something very similar to cubic 2D curves (like Bézier curves used in SVG and many other 2D vector formats), in an exploration for true 2D curve support for 3D printers and 2D/2.5D CNC mills. Are your curves polynomial (degree?) or what?